# how to format money column in table element vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

how to format number or money column in vue js
here is my column

```
<el-table-column :label="columnHeader.amount" prop="amount" sortable min-width="140">
  <template slot-scope="props">
      <div v-if="!props.row.amount">-</div>
         <div v-else style="text-transform: capitalize;">
           {{ props.row.amount }}
      </div>
  </template>
</el-table-column>
```

in props.row.amount i want format be number like 10,000 any body can help

Comment: use Numbers `toLocaleString` method - e.g., `props.row.amount.toLocaleString()`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript